# Users unable to view orders even with permissions set

Tags: 7, users, ubercart

I have a Drupal 7 site with Ubercart.  When users log in, and check their "My Orders" tab, it says there are no orders even when their should be.  Users are showing correctly for admin, and permissions are set correctly for them to view.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: I don't know exactly what might be causing this, but since it sounds like a permissions problem, here's something I have done in the past to track it down. Create a new Role, give it all of the permissions just as an Admin, create a user with that role, and make sure it has an order in place. If the order shows correctly, start taking out permissions until the order disappears and you'll know which permission is the culprit - might be something completely bizarre and seemingly unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said the permissions are set right you can do a quick test for this using views;

Create a new view with "show" Orders and use the Filters(users) to check if you can find the orders of different users.